# Can we make the Azure Access Review Dynamic

Tags: azure-active-directory

we have number of Teams that may be created in a month, and it becomes difficult to setup Access Review for 100s of groups that comes up every month. So is there a way where we can setup access review based on site classification? Or alternatively can we dynamically add new groups to the existing access review created?

Are there any limitation to the number of groups that can be added to the access review?

Does Access Review support Power Shell Script so that we will add new groups by running the Power Shell on daily basis or are there any APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, its not possible to make the Azure Access Review Dynamic. However, you can voice your interest in such a feature or [support similar ones](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/40955806-dynamically-update-access-reviews-with-new-groups) in the Azure AD Feedback Forum.

Selecting more than one group will create multiple access reviews. For example, selecting five groups will create five separate access reviews.There is no documented limit for the numbers of access reviews that you can create.

You can, however, create access reviews using APIs. What you do to manage access reviews of groups and application users in the Azure portal can also be done using Microsoft Graph APIs. For more information, see the [Azure AD access reviews API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/accessreviews-root?view=graph-rest-beta).